# Android: Is there a way to "setDuration" for a loop to running ? use Thread.Sleep?

Tags: android

I am trying to making a for loop to finish running around 5 seconds.  I am trying to figure out a way to do this by maybe calculating a Thread.Sleep method for take up time to fill the set 5 seconds for maybe a 8 loop count.  Is there a better way to do this or should I use a Timer Task or related?

I am looking for a efficient and smart way to do this. thanks.

Comment: First, don't do that on the UI thread or you'll have nasty performance problems...

Now what exactly do you want to do during those 5 seconds? If it's nothing, Thread.Sleep can work. If you want to do something, you can test the time that has passed each loop with System.currentTimeMillis().

Comment: i want to draw a progress bar from 0 to maybe 80% in realtime in about 5 second for visual effects on the UI in Android App.  I am setting a new draw and invalidate on each loop iteration so the total time to see the progress bar to reach 80% from 0 is 5 seconds

Comment: Best would be to use a 5s timer then to update your ProgressBar. That's how I'd do it, it's simple and only takes a few lines of code.

Comment: @YoungBrogrammer : Post code to show us what you are trying to achieve and what you've tried so far.

Comment: well, i want to show the progress of the draw from 0 to 80 percent within 5 secs, to just clarify.  so i guess i have to calculate the time for the timer within 5 secs right,  i was hoping for something like at "setDuration" kinda solution to show the progressbar draw progress from 0 to 80%.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code also

SystemClock.sleep(5000);

This is 5 second delay